# Parse or convert .pb files under .sonar folder

Tags: parsing, sonarqube, protobuf-net

I'm using sonarqube 5.6.5,everything works well . Now i need to parse the issues.PB file generated under .sonar/batch-report/ folder.  i tried using jsonformat but it is not working.

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] your question to include your end goal?

Answer (score 1):

They are "Protobuf" format, which is a format by google for serializing data. You can get started [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) or find for example a tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial) on how to use it in Java.

What I don't understand is that your question has a tag "protobuf-net", which [github page](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) explains very well how to use it (in .NET).